# How can I perform COALESCE in power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table that has values for quarters and I need to add a new column that gives me the last not null value as last quarter. For example

```
ID | Project  | Q1   | Q2   | Q3   | Q4   | Current Quarter Value  
1  | bal bal  | 23   | 32   | 34   | null | 34  
2  | cuz cuz  | 43   | 56   | null | null | 56
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a couple formulas you can use when adding a custom column to the table (accessible from the Transform ribbon tab). Here's one:

`if [Q4] <> null then [Q4] else if [Q3] <> null then [Q3] else if [Q2] <> null then [Q2] else [Q1]`

If you don't want to write so many if statements, you can add the columns to a list and filter out the null values:

`List.Last(List.Select({[Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4]}, each _ <> null))`

Comment: What does it fail on? What does your query look like? Could you copy the code shown in the Advanced Editor for the query?

Comment: ended up using the nested if solution... not practical, but it works, thanks!

Comment: I would use `List.Last(List.RemoveNulls({[Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4]}))`

Comment: If I could give +10, I would. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeHoney why `List.Last` ? Why last, not first. Shouldn't it be [Q1] if its not empty? Or does not Last sellect Q4 if its not null?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin you are probably right - I was building on Alejandro's example.

Answer (score 26):

You can try the *null coalescing operator (??)*. Both of the following lines achieve the same effect of returning `ValueA` unless it is null, in which case `ValueB` is returned.

```
if ValueA <> null then ValueA else ValueB
ValueA ?? ValueB
```

Applied to your specific case the necessary code would be:

```
[Q4] ?? [Q3] ?? [Q2] ?? [Q1]
```

Note that the null coalescing operator is a [new addition](https://github.com/microsoft/powerquery-parser/issues/173) to Power Query. It has not been officially documented yet and may [not](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-powerquery/issues/56#issuecomment-663633751) be available in all environments.

*Information taken from [this blog post](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/01/06/4844/power-query-m-primer-part14-control-structure).*

Comment: Wow this is a far more elegant solution for most situations! +1

Comment: This is really good!

Answer (score 3):

It's great how the Power Query M Language has developed over time. And luckily the null coalescing operator has been introduced. It's represented by ??

The easiest way to do a COALESCE is by using the last example. But you can use any of the following methods:

```
= null ?? null ?? 1 ?? 2
= List.First( List.RemoveNulls( { null, null, 1, 2 } ) )
= List.First( List.RemoveFirstN( { null, null, 1, 2 }, each _ = null ) )
= List.RemoveFirstN( { null, null, 1, 2 }, each _ = null ){0}
= List.Select( { null, null, 1, 2 }, each _ <> null ){0}
```

More explanation on this you can find here:
https://gorilla.bi/power-query/coalesce/

Cheers, Rick

Answer (score 0):

I think is a little bit late, but I'm also looking for a better solution than:
List.First( List.RemoveNulls( { list } ) )

or for a default value:

List.First( List.RemoveNulls( List.Combine { { list }, { defaultValue } } ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Using List.RemoveNulls bothered me because it seems to do more work than necessary.

Here is a function that appears to avoid processing the whole list, beyond the first non-null item:

coalesce = each List.First(List.RemoveFirstN(_, each _ = null), null)