# Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text. Details: Value= Type=Type

Tags: excel, automation, powerbi, powerquery

I want to combine multiple files with different headings and i found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKglApDFMog) which was perfect. I get up to minute 12 and it fails and i get this error "Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text.
Details:
Value=
Type=Type"

my code for the power query is `= Table.TransformColumnNames(stuff_Table, each List.Accumulate(Table.ToRecords(Headings), _ , (state, current)=>Text.Replace(Text.Upper(state), current [BEFORE],current[AFTER]) ))`

I want to combine three files. One with a template that will be used for tableau but is otherwise blank, and the other two files with the data but in inconsistent formatting. How do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide sufficient information to allow someone to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to apply a transformation that takes TEXT as input on data of type NULL. This means that PowerQuery is expecting a textual input but receives nothing. You need to make sure it receives a textual input (by adapting your source & replacing null with a text value), or that your PowerQuery formula handles null values explicitly (typically by some variation of "if field = null then "empty" else field").

`Text.Replace(Text.Upper(state)` ==> Most likely, the **state** field is NULL in at least one instance (one line) of your source. Maybe the Tableau template file?

Try replacing empty fields by "null" or "empty" or "no state" or even a white space " "). This can be done either manually within the source (transform the column or create a new column) or within PowerQuery.

A quick google search on "Power query replace Null with text" gives a range of options.

- [How can I perform COALESCE in power query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405094/how-can-i-perform-coalesce-in-power-query)
- https://www.edureka.co/community/40467/replace-null-values-custom-values-power-power-query-editor
- https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Replace-NULL/m-p/106183

Comment: Yeah this was what waas the problem. In my mapping table I had to remove the gaps and it worked. Thanks